# Как найти нужный сериализатор json на Android?

Tags: шаблоны, json, java, android, сериализация

Нужен сериализатор, который использует модели (шаблоны).
Например:

```
Data.serialize(some model)
```

И, соответственно, где-то мы описываем модели:

```
model one:
Json.put(value, value);
Json.put(value, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

[gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) прекрасно работает в связке с [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)